# Garbage collection in Tensorflow 1.14

Tags: tensorflow

When a variable is created, it is added to collections to allow sharing and reusing. However, this seems like it's a potential for "memory leaks" (strictly speaking, it's not, since there still exists a reference). How should I deal with this?

If I do something like:

```
import tensorflow as tf
g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default():
    tf.get_variable('myvar', shape=(2, 2))
del g
```

will `myvar` be garbage collected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Tensorflow 1.*, `myvar` will not be collected even if you lost track of the variable pointing to it, till the Python process terminates.

In Tensorfow 2.* it will be collected by the garbage collector.

For details, see [the blog](https://medium.com/tensorflow/effective-tensorflow-2-0-best-practices-and-whats-changed-a0ca48767aff) by Tensorflow, under the *"No more globals"* section.